# How to use ng-change between two controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="oneCtrl">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="dt" ng-change="changeDate(dt)" /> 
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open($event)">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
        </button>
    </span>
    <div class="row"  ng-controller="twoCtrl"> 
        <!-- Here is the use of dt -->
    </div>
</body>
```

When `ng-change` is happening, I want to use `changeDate(dt)` function's value in `twoCtrl`.

Comment: Please refer accepted answer in this [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30174063/button-radio-change-value-in-another-controller-with-ng-click-in-angular-js)

Answer (score 0):

With help of directive we can do as follows

**HTML file**

```
<div ng-controller="firstController">
    {{name}} 
    <button my-directive>
      invoke function
    </button>
  <div ng-controller="secondController">
    {{name}}
  </div>

</div>
```

**JS file**

```
angular.module("myApp", [])

.controller("firstController", function($scope, $rootScope){
    $scope.name = "Ctrl-1";
  var listener = $rootScope.$on("MYEVENT", function(){
    alert("IM CTRL 1");
  });

  $scope.$on("$destroy", function(){
    listener(); //de-registering event
  });

})

.controller("secondController", function($scope, $rootScope){
    $scope.name = "Ctrl-2";
  var listener = $rootScope.$on("MYEVENT", function(){
    alert("IM CTRL 2");
  });
  $scope.$on("$destroy", function(){
    listener();
  });
})

.directive("myDirective", function($rootScope){
    return{
    restrict: "AE",
    scope: {},
    link: function(scope, ele, attrs){
        ele.bind("click", function(){
        $rootScope.$broadcast("MYEVENT");
      });       
    }
  }
})
```